# imagecreate() works fine when php script in ran from browser , but not when it is run from the shell

Tags: php, shell

I have image creating php script . It works fine when i access it from the browser . But when it is called from a shell script it shows the following error .

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imagecreate()

Comment: cli php can/will use different .ini files than the sapi(browser) version. check that GD is being loaded into your cli php setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP CLI probably doesn't use the same configuration file than the browser one. So it doesn't load the GD library.

You could either force him to use the same .ini file :

```
php -c /directory/php.ini phpscript.php
```

Or add the following line in your PHP CLI configuration file :

```
; Enable gd extension module
extension=gd.so
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the gd is loaded and try to load it dynamically

```
<?php
if (!extension_loaded('gd')) {
    if (!dl('gd.so')) {
        echo "GD cannot be loaded";
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```